# Devon no longer has the book that the teacher had given him because he was leaving it in the library

Tags: tense

> Devon no longer has the book that the teacher had given him because he **was leaving** it in the library.

Which tense is correct about the last part: "was leaving"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Elena. We expect people to do a little research before asking a question: in this case, you could find out a little more about the differences between simple past and past continuous by reading an article like this: http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/past-continuous-and-past-simple. If that doesn't answer your question, please edit your question to explain what specifically you don't understand, and provide links to the research that you found confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the example sentence is perfectly idiomatic in its choice of tenses. It begins in the present tense, and so there's no real need for the past perfect, although it is not incorrect.

> Devon no longer **has** the book (that) the teacher **gave** him.

Why does Devon not have the book any longer?

> He **left** it in the library.
>
> He **has left** it in the library.

Either of those tense would work, simple past or present perfect.  The past refers to the act as something that happened.  The present perfect refers to the event from the point of view of the present moment.

> I **forgot** my car keys **yesterday** and I *realize* that I **have forgotten** them *again today*.

With respect to the continuous, you could say

> Devon is developing a bad *habit*: he **has been leaving** things
>   wherever he uses them last.

And once this developing habit is fully developed:

> Devon **leaves** things wherever he uses them last.